# g++ Argument list too long

Tags: windows, gcc, g++, codeblocks, mingw32

I am compiling my code using the MinGW toolchain. I have hundreds of files in my projects, that cannot be changed, so hundreds of object files are produced. During linking the g++.exe command failes because the argument list is too long.
Is there a way to fix this issue under Windows?

Comment: Use an argument file? See [@file](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Overall-Options.html#index-fdump-go-spec).

Answer (score 0):

Given that it would be interesting to see how the tree of directories of the files is organized, you could divide the project into several libraries and compile them separately. 
Later you could statically (or dynamically) to link the various libraries to compile the overall project.